# Endian Swap in C Union

Tags: c, swap, endianness, unions

I am trying to understand the way an endian swap works when done within a union in C. I understand that a union has the ability to hold multiple types of data, but can only hold one type at a time. The code I am trying to understand looks like this, this is the union definition:

```
  union byte4 {
          char byte[4];
          int numint;
          float numfloat;
  };
```

This is the function.

```
  int endianSwap4int(int a) {
      union byte4 un;
      un.numint = a;

      // swap
      char c1 = un.byte[0];
      un.byte[0] = un.byte[3];
      un.byte[3] = c1;
      c1 = un.byte[1];
      un.byte[1] = un.byte[2];
      un.byte[2] = c1;

      return un.numint;
  }
```

In the function, if the input `a` is 2048327680, the function returns 6010 when `un.numint` is returned. I understand that manipulating `un.byte` is indirectly manipulating `un.numint` as well because unions can only hold one thing at a time, but I don't understand exactly how they affect each other, so my question is, how exactly do they affect each other?

Comment: All members of the union share the very same memory region. They only provide different interpretations when accessed. The byte-array abstraction allows an easy shuffle of the individual bytes. Doing so directly effects the value of the overlaid `int` because they do reference the same memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the hex representation of `2048327680`, you'll see it is `7A 17 00 00`.  So if your machine stores this value in little endian format, the LSB is stored first.

If we add extra debugging to `endianSwap4int` as follows:

```
  int endianSwap4int(int a) {
      union byte4 un;
      int i;
      un.numint = a;

      printf("before:\n");
      for (i=0;i<4;i++) {
          printf("un[%d]=%02X\n", i, un.byte[i]);
      }

      // swap
      char c1 = un.byte[0];
      un.byte[0] = un.byte[3];
      un.byte[3] = c1;
      c1 = un.byte[1];
      un.byte[1] = un.byte[2];
      un.byte[2] = c1;

      printf("after:\n");
      for (i=0;i<4;i++) {
          printf("un[%d]=%02X\n", i, un.byte[i]);
      }
      return un.numint;
  }
```

You'll see the following output:

```
before:
un[0]=00
un[1]=00
un[2]=17
un[3]=7A
after:
un[0]=7A
un[1]=17
un[2]=00
un[3]=00
```

Here, you can see that the LSB of the original number is first before the swap, and the MSB of the original number is first after the swap.  So now the `int` portion of the union contains the value `00 00 17 7A` which in decimal is `6010`.